# Insert script via CSS content property

Tags: css, tags

Is it possible to insert script tag using content property of CSS?

The example below inserts plain text instead of a html tag

```
#someDiv:before {
    content:"<script>$(function(){ console.log('test');});</script>";
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Content inserted with the `content` property will only ever be plain text. This is to prevent recursion. It also helps by preventing people from doing crazy things like inserting `script` elements with CSS.